# Vim visually select a Bash variable

Tags: vim

In this code:

```
printf "%-${field_length}s : %b%s${my_text_style_plain}\n" \
...
```

my cursor is on the letter `p` of `my_text_style_plain`.

I would like to visually select this:

```
${my_text_style_plain}
```

the sequences <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> select this:

```
{my_text_style_plain}
```

Failing to conveniently select exactly what I'd like, I could be happy with quickly moving to the `$` or `{`.

I know I can just <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> but really I need to "backward find" the enclosing brace often, when I am in the middle of a multi-line function and I'd like to rename it for instance, so that might be useful as well.

<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> is in this case limited because it only finds the `{` if on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've said, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> selects `{my_text_style_plain}` (even across multiple lines).

To quickly select the leading `$` as well, you can do <kbd>o</kbd> to jump to the start of the visual selection and then <kbd>h</kbd> to extend it one character to the left.

Of course, if this is something you need to do a lot you could map it to some other key.

Comment: 1. thx for teaching me about `<kbd>` 2. `o` is excellent, I'll wait for a more specific answer (bash vars) otherwise I'll happily accept.. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

you can execute this or add it to your vimrc: (Around Variable)

```
onoremap av :<c-u>normal! F$vf}<cr>
```

so that you could do: (cursor between `$` and `}`)

```
cav   - remove the ${foo} and switch to insert mode
dav   - delete the ${foo}
yav   - yank the ${foo}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <F6> F$vf}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `iskeyword+=$` to make Vim recognize the dollar sign as a keyword. This only helps for `$VAR` and not for `${VAR}`, though.

```
autocmd FileType sh setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

Pressing `viw` would then select the `$`, too. This is particularly helpful in combination with [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).